# using jest and enzyme testing useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can I test the `useEffect` for one time call, so I am loading a number of links on mount. so it will be called only once

see the code

app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const links = createLinks();
        setLinks(links);
    }, []);

    const createLinks = () => {
        return [{ link: "https://www.google.com", text: "Google" }];
    };

    return <>{links.length && links.map(({ link, text }) => <a href={link}>{text}</a>)}</>;
};


export default App
```

how can i write a test case for the above sample app component using jest and enzyme

Comment: Have you tried using Jest mocks (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) + the have been called n times method?

Comment: If you're importing `createLinks()` from somewhere, you can use `jest.mock()` to sub that out for an instance of `jest.fn()`. That can return a value using `mockFunc.mockReturnValueOnce(links)`. Then check it's only been called once by asserting `mockFunc.mock.calls.length === 1`

Comment: createLinks is a function inside the component i am not importing it ? as you can see the code

Comment: there is not much docs, since enzyme also doesn't any further docs on the same. tried using act from react-dom-tesing that also didnt given any much input i am new to this so is there any way to solve this.

Comment: Oops didn't see that. You can just move it to a separate file or even keep it in the same file but move it into the upper scope and `export const createLinks =` etc. Not sure if there's any other way to do it with Jest

Comment: @adamz4008 i was not able to find a way, if the question seems to be answered it will be helpful if you can upvote it

Comment: The test is as simple as rendering the component and making sure the appropriate link gets shown. That's the behaviour; the fact that you're using useEffect to call a function that makes the list then mapping the list to elements is an irrelevant implementation detail (and seems kind of pointless).

Comment: so whats the better way directly storing the links in the array and just doing a map and finding the a tag is that what you are referring.