# Tesing the store file in Redux using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

How can we write the test for the store creation file using Jest and Enzyme?

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store;
```

i had tried with this, is it required.

```
import store from "..";

describe("store", () => {
    it("should create a store", () => {
        expect(store).toEqual(
            expect.objectContaining({
                dispatch: expect.any(Function),
                getState: expect.any(Function),
            })
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Unit testing? I wouldn't bother. The whole app won't work as expected if that wiring is wrong, so you'll catch it in a higher level test.

Comment: so no need to test it isn't, i was thinking of having 100 percent coverage!!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had tried using expect is it required as shown in the question, but seeing 100 percent green for the coverage makes so happy :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was trying some custom hooks test cases and test case for useEffect and useState, i was using enzyme and jest, since enzyme doesn't have much docs i was using react testing library, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173156/making-the-window-to-different-data-type-in-react-testing-library ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169619/using-jest-and-enzyme-testing-useeffect-and-usestate

both of them doesn't have an answer, is there any idea .on this ?

Comment: Are you testing if `createStore` works? I'm pretty sure you don't need to do that. You might need to test whether the default store state has certain values in it though or when dispatching an action the state changes as expected. However the latter might be better tested by unit testing the reducers.

Comment: @apokryfos should i test like what i have tried or is there any better way to achieve it. Basically i am trying to see 100% test coverage for the file

Comment: Having 100% coverage is not strictly necessary, in this case because `createStore` is already being unit tested in the redux library (so you don't need to). But if you must have 100% code coverage then what you're doing is fine

Comment: @apokryfos cool thanks. as i am new to testing do u have any fair  idea on this  two questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169619/using-jest-and-enzyme-testing-useeffect-and-usestate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173156/making-the-window-to-different-data-type-in-react-testing-library

Answer (score -1):

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock'

const middlewares = [thunk]
// mocking store
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('some async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.restore()
  })
})
```